# How to get the content of a XML node in R?

Tags: xml, r

I have a stupid question to ask : how to get the content of a XML node in R ? For instance, in the code :

```
<p attribute="blabla">this is what I need</p>
```

I need to get a variable with only the string "this is what I need". To help you I precise that I parsed the code oh the webpage with XMLNodeSet.

Than you by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. using the `XML` package:

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse('<p attribute="blabla">this is what I need</p>', asText = TRUE)
xmlValue(doc[["/html/body/p/text()"]]  )
# [1] "this is what I need"
```